# Computing the seven roots of a polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry, number-theory

This question was originally asked by [@fsrong70](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/59243/fsrong70) six months ago. 
The OP deleted it shortly after posting and has not returned to this site since.  I had just figured it out when it was deleted.  I waited to see if the OP would repost it, but not yet.  So I'm posting it with my solution.

---

Considering the solution to the following equation

$x^7+x^6-18 x^5-35 x^4+38 x^3+104 x^2+7 x-49=0$

```
poly = x^7 + x^6 - 18 x^5 - 35 x^4 + 38 x^3 + 104 x^2 + 7 x - 49;
```

This problem could be solved using notions from Galois theory and the Galois group of a polynomial, and the 43rd root of unity ($\displaystyle e^\frac{2i\pi}{43}$)
.

The solutions are expressed in terms of trigonometric (cosine) functions.
The seven solutions are:

$\displaystyle \alpha_1 = 2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{12\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{14\pi}{43})$

$\displaystyle \alpha_2 =2\cos(\frac{4\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{24\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{28\pi}{43})$

$\displaystyle \alpha_3 = 2\cos(\frac{6\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{36\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{42\pi}{43})$

$\displaystyle \alpha_4 =2\cos(\frac{8\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{30\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{38\pi}{43})$

$\displaystyle \alpha_5 =2\cos(\frac{10\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{16\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{24\pi}{43})$

$\displaystyle \alpha_6 =2\cos(\frac{18\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{22\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{40\pi}{43})$

$\displaystyle \alpha_7 =2\cos(\frac{20\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{32\pi}{43}) + 2\cos(\frac{34\pi}{43})$

Might this problem be entirely solved and the symbolic solutions computed with Mathematica?

This problem was asked and solved on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-i-solve-the-polynomial-x-7-x-6-18x-5-35x-4-38x-3-104x-2-7x-49-0-via-radicals), but not in relation to *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
poly = x^7 + x^6 - 18 x^5 - 35 x^4 + 38 x^3 + 104 x^2 + 7 x - 49;
```

Find an extension in which the polynomial splits:

```
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock[Infinity], n};
Catch[
  Do[
   fl = DeleteCases[
     FactorList[poly, Extension -> Exp[2 Pi*I/n]], {_?NumericQ, _Integer}];
   If[Total[fl[[All, 2]]] > 1, Throw[n -> fl]], {n, 
    Rest@Divisors@Discriminant[poly, x]}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solve:

```
Apply[Join, Solve[First@# == 0, x] & /@ fl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Cosmetic clean-up:

```
roots = Expand[
    Apply[Join, Solve[First@# == 0, x] & /@ fl] /. -1 + rest__ :> 
      Simplify[Sum[2 Cos[2 Pi/43*k], {k, 21}] + rest]
    ] /. {2 Sin[t_] :> 2 Inactive[Cos][Pi/2 - t],
         -2 Sin[t_] :> 2 Inactive[Cos][Pi/2 + t],
         -2 Cos[t_] :> 2 Inactive[Cos][Pi + t],
          2 Cos[t_] :> 2 Inactive[Cos][t]} // 
  SortBy[Min@Cases[#, Inactive[Cos][t_] :> N@t, Infinity] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note there's an error in $a_5$ in the OP.

*Update:*
Here's the fastest way I've found to verify:

```
FullSimplify@TrigToExp@Activate[poly /. roots] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {4.84673, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}  *)
```

Comment: Note that substituting the roots into `poly` and using `Simplify` to see if they satisfy it takes a very long time. (Using `N` after substituting gives verification almost immediately, rhough.)

Comment: @murray Yes, it does.  This is a bit faster: `FullSimplify @ TrigToExp@Activate[poly /. roots]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve this problem with [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) software.
If the Galois group of a polynomial is solvable, Magma can give all of its root solutions.

```
> P<x> := PolynomialRing(IntegerRing()); 
> f := x^7 + x^6 - 18* x^5 - 35 *x^4 + 38* x^3 + 104* x^2 + 7* x - 49;
> G:=GaloisGroup (f);
> G;
> IsCyclic (G);
> IsSolvable (G);
> K, R := SolveByRadicals(f:Name := "K."); 
> K:Maximal; 
> R;
```

The result we get back is

```
Permutation group G acting on a set of cardinality 7
Order = 7
    (1, 3, 6, 7, 2, 5, 4)
true
true
The computation exceeded the time limit and so was terminated prematurely.
```

You may need a desktop version of Magma to be free of computing time constraints
(In fact,before v2.25-2, the magma web page version can calculate the results within the specified time. It is estimated that the new web version of magma in a few months will fix this bug).

But the following [example](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/404#4294) can get the calculation result

```
> P<x> := PolynomialRing(IntegerRing());
> f := x^6 - x^5 - 6*x^4 + 7*x^3 + 4*x^2 - 5*x + 1;
> K, R := SolveByRadicals(f:Name := "K.");
> K:Maximal;

  K<K.1>

     |

     |
  $1<K.2>
     |

     |
  $2<K.3>
     |
     |
  $3<K.4>
     |

     |
    Q

K  : K.1^3 + 1/2*(3*K.4 - 11)*K.3 + 1/2*(-27*K.4 + 23)
$1 : K.2^3 - 114*K.4*K.3 - 494
$2 : K.3^2 - 5
$3 : K.4^2 + 3
> [ Evaluate(f, x) eq 0 : x in R];
[ true, true, true, true, true, true ]
```

K.4 is a solution of k.4 ^ 2 + 3. Let k.4 = sqrt [- 3]
K.3 is a solution of K.3 ^ 2 - 5. Let K.3 = sqrt [5]

K.2 is a solution of K.2^3 - 114*K.4*K.3 - 494,that's a solution of K.2^3 - 114*Sqrt[-15] - 494,Let k.2=K.2=Power[38 (13+3 Sqrt[-15]), (3)^-1]

K.1 is a solution of K.1^3 + 1/2*(3*K.4 - 11)*K.3 + 1/2*(-27*K.4 + 23),that's a solution of K.1^3 + 1/2*(3*Sqrt[-3] - 11)*Sqrt[5] + 1/2*(-27*Sqrt[-3] + 23),Let K.1=I Power[1/2 (-23 I-27 Sqrt[3]+11 Sqrt[-5]+3 Sqrt[15]), (3)^-1]

So one of the roots of f := x^6 - x^5 - 6*x^4 + 7*x^3 + 4*x^2 - 5*x + 1 is

```
(1/456*(-3*K.4 + 7)*K.3 + 1/456*(-27*K.4 - 13))*K.1^2 + 1/3*K.1 + 1/6*K.3 + 1/6
=(1/456*(-3*Sqrt[-3] + 7)*Sqrt[5] + 1/456*(-27*Sqrt[-3] - 13))*I Power[1/2 (-23 I-27 Sqrt[3]+11 Sqrt[-5]+3 Sqrt[15]), (3)^-1]^2 + 1/3*I Power[1/2 (-23 I-27 Sqrt[3]+11 Sqrt[-5]+3 Sqrt[15]), (3)^-1] + 1/6*Sqrt[5] + 1/6
```

Comment: But this isn't a *Mathematica* solution...